# in Django how do I pass a reversed url with arbitrary arguments from a template to a view

Tags: django, templates

I have a view:

```
def partnered_item_edit(request, item_id, return_to='delivery_manager'):
   item = get_object_or_404(PartneredItem, pk=item_id)
...    
delivery.save()
return redirect(return_to)
```

The purpose of this is to make it reusable so I can use this view from different places in the program and have it redirect to the view where the user was working previously.

In the template I have:

```
<p><a href="{% url 'partnered_item_edit' item_id=item.id return_to='delivery_view' %}" class="btn btn-default ...
```

The view I currently want to redirect to is declared like this:

```
def delivery_view(request, delivery_id):
    delivery = get_object_or_404(Delivery, pk=delivery_id)
...
```

but I will also want it to redirect to this at other parts of the program such as:

```
def delivery_manager(request):
     date = datetime.date.today()
```

(this one does not require the `delivery_id`)

I would also like to hook this view into other templates as well, and use this technique for other redirect / view combos.  Basically I'm looking for something that allows me to do:

```
reverse('delivery_view', args=('delivery_id'))
```

or

```
reverse('delivery_manager')
```

in the template.

Then again... am I trying to make this work the hard way?  Do I need to make a template filter to make this work?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to change a bit logic of `partnered_item_edit` view:

```
def partnered_item_edit(request, item_id, return_to_delivery=False):
   item = get_object_or_404(PartneredItem, pk=item_id)

   ...   
   delivery.save()

   if return_to_delivery:
       return redirect('delivery_view', args=(delivery.pk,))
   else:
       return redirect('delivery_manager')
```

If you want to edit an item and redirect to delivery manager use in template:

```
{% url 'partnered_item_edit' item_id=item.id %}
```

Otherwise if you want to redirect to delivery use:

```
{% url 'partnered_item_edit' item_id=item.id return_to_delivery=True %}
```

Hope these helps!